# Check validity produces error output at origin although no polygon is there QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, geometry

After running 'Check Validity' I keep getting an 'error output' dot at the origin for my shapefile although there is no feature there.

This is the only error, and I think may be why my intersection is not working.
Even after putting my file through mapshaper to try to simplify it, I keep getting this error output point at the origin.

I am not sure how to fix this problem, or if it even is a problem, perhaps it is just a normal artifact of the process and my error is elsewhere. Could it be that I could have a feature without a geometry at this point?

The shapefile was originally in equal area projection, then re-projected to WGS84, however I do not think this is related.

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem right now and already had in the past. The other time it was in a shape to which I didn't need to do any more operations, so I left it like that. This time I really need to fix it. Somehow I think this problem appears in shapes that had been converted from CAD files... Can anyone help us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Difficult to tell without seeing the actual data, but this will help to debug situations like this.

If you used **Vector > Geometry Tools > Check Validity**, you should see a point layer called "Error output". I drew a couple of "bow ties" (which have self intersections) to test this.

[image]

<kbd>Right click</kbd> on the Error Output layer and open the **Attribute Editor**

[image]

The message column should show the error message. You might also get **Invalid output** layers, if so, check these too.

Comment: The error message says 'unknown geometry', while I can't see any nodes, when I look up '$geometry IS NULL', I don't find anything, it is tricky